# Error in pom.xml when adding sauce labs dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-2, webdriver, saucelabs

I am getting errors when I add sauce labs dependency in my pom xml.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>sauce_testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Is any one seeing the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

The artifact is stored in the Sauce Labs Maven repository, can you add the following into your pom.xml file?

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
       <id>Sauce Maven Repository</id>
       <url>https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

Comment: Dumb question - does it matter where in the POM we put the repository info?  I tried this and Maven still can't seem to find the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The artifact that you are referring to is not in central. Are you sure that you have the info?

I have found this info

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
<artifactId>sauce-rest-api</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
```

Comment: Thats what I thought. Actually the repo is here http://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/saucelabs/sauce_testng/

Comment: That is on cloudbees. Which means the package that you want is still under construction. If you think that the package of 1.1 doesn't have what you need, then you can download the jar and put it in your repository. Check here http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html